# Finding the max element in an array, sorted ascending first and then descending

Tags: python, arrays, binary-search

I tried an online challenge which had a question as follows:

> You are given an array which increases at first and then starts decreasing.
>   For example: `2 3 4 5 6 7 8 6 4 2 0 -2`.
>   Find the maximum element of these array.

Following is my code using binary search and it gives correct answer in O(log(n)) but I don't know whether there is a better solution or not. 
Can anyone help me with that?

```
a= map(int, raw_input().split())
def BS(lo,hi):
    mid = lo+ (hi-lo)/2
    if a[mid]>=a[mid+1]:
        if a[mid]>a[mid-1]:
            return mid
        else:
            return BS(lo,mid)
    else:
        return BS(mid,hi)

print a[BS(0,len(a)-1)]
```

Comment: Looks good to me. O(log n) is likely the best you can do (ignoring constant factors, or different logarithmic bases).

Comment: How can you do a binary search on an unsorted array?

Comment: @haraldkl Its a modified binary search, code is given above, try it.

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal got it now, overlooked the special description for the array sorting at first, and your title says unsorted array. It would be nice if you could explicitly state "modified" binary search for your solution, and not unsorted in the title.

Comment: @ShubhamAggarwal Definitely your solution is perfect. because you can do it by `O(nlogn)`. All Others solution are do it by O(n). So, your complexity is better from others.

Comment: @S_A: O(n log n) is worse than O(n), not better. You meant O(log n)?

Comment: @mhawke:  Opps sorry. Yes I mean `O(log n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An optimised variant - twice faster in most cases:

```
# ® Видул Николаев Петров
a = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 24, 48, 12, 6, 5, 0, -1]

def calc(a):
    if len(a) <= 2:
        return a[0] if a[0] > a[1]  else a[1]

    l2 = len(a) / 2

    if a[l2 + 1] <= a[l2] and a[l2] >= a[l2 - 1]:
        return a[l2]

    if a[l2] > a[l2 + 1]:
        return calc(a[:l2+1])
    else:
        return calc(a[l2:])

print calc(a) # 48
```

Comment: very well! This can be an optimization

Answer (score 1):

i am trying your code with the following input 2 3 4 5 5 8 and the answer should be **8** but the answer is **5** i am posting an image with a few more test cases [image]

i think u cannot run binary search on an unsorted array
the code also gives huge list of exceptions for sorted arrays

Comment: This is not an unsorted array, it is possible to run a binary search in this array. The problem is likely that the OP didn't consider the edge-case of when a number was at either the start or end. I bet that if you add a number to the end that is smaller, then it will give the correct results.

Comment: when testing with 3 4 5 7 there is a huge list of runtime exceptions occuring

Comment: That is why it was failing a test case. Thanks a lot for pointing it out man!

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use the `max()` method??

`max(lst)` will return the max value in a list

Comment: The Python `max` is not allowed. It has to be implemented.

Comment: and the list comprehesions are not allowed?